# How to make header show only on home page? Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the website I am editing with wordpress:

www.thestudentbubble.com

As you can see there is a 'header' the 3 lines explaining what the site is about. 
How do I makke this appear only on the Home Page?

I found the Header.php file and the code looks like this currently:

```
<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
              <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You can use the below mentioned options. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

Wordpress [is_home()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) function.
You can also use [is_frontpage()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

Little more information on what is difference between these:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
} elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
  // static homepage
} elseif ( is_home() ) {
  // blog page
} else {
  //everyting else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it all works now!

used <?php endif; ?> thought but all good :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [is_home](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) function to check if you are in the home page.

```
<?php if (is_home()): ?>
    <!-- ... -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in if condition like this--

```
if( is_front_page())
{
   ///put code here to show only on home page header 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A neater solution would be changing the existing condition (which presumably will fallback nicely if it fails) to:

`<?php if ( get_header_image() && is_home() ) : ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted my Wordpress template's header image to display only on the main page and **not** to display it on any of the other pages.

I had to edit the template's **header.php** file and add:

```
<!-- Custom Header - Start -->
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) :   ?>
   $header_image = get_header_image();
   [...]
<?php endif; // end check for featured image or standard header ?>
```